# Python behaves erratically using cx_freeze

Tags: cx-freeze

I wrote a python 2.7 script to scrape webpages and output a JSON file.
When I run my script in an IDE or by running the .py file, it works no problem.
But when I use cx_freeze to make an exe and run it, I get errors such as IndexError.

I believe I have traced the problem to BeautifulSoup.
I have many statements such as: soup.find_all('td').
That statement returns me a list. When my script runs, that list is populated with the results, but when I run my exe, it always gives an empty list [].

So for some reason, I believe that bs4 is not working properly under cx_freeze. I am parsing the exact same webpage, the exact same HTML is being fed into the soup, but find_all is not giving me anything in the .exe, but in .py it works fine.

Anyone have any ideas on what I can do to resolve this issue? I get similar problems with other builders such as py2exe and I don't even want to get started with pyinstaller. I'd rather just deal with cx_freeze.

My Python environment is Python xy running Python 2.7. cx_freeze plugin is installed, and bs4 is included in my setup.py.

Comment: Kindly post your `setup.py` and the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec code in m.__dict__
  File "scraper.py", line 1124, in <module>
  File "scraper.py", line 668, in get_summary
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os", "bs4", "collections", "codecs", "datetime", "io", "json", "re", "sys", "urllib2"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None

setup(  name = "appname",
        version = "0.0",
        description = "desc",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("scraper.py", base=base)])

Comment: It would be very strange for `soup.find_all()` to work differently in a frozen exe, which makes me think that BeautifulSoup is either getting different input, or using a different backend to parse it. Have you checked that?

Comment: @ThomasK I have checked. the 'soup' variable contents is the same when running via .py and .exe. It is just for some reason the .exe find_all is not working. It is very strange indeed. 

Both are exact. One is just .py and the other is .exe. They both get data from the same page, yet something is broken.